# cannot boot from usb and grub! ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have an HP ProBook 5330m with SSD, without CD, and Windows 7. I also installed ubuntu 12.10 and have been dual booting for many months now. Something went wrong and now I can't boot my laptop at all!

The error message is

```
error: invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

Another problem is that I cannot boot from USB! I tried to create usb startup disks - ubuntu live CD, supergrub, ... but when I configure the USB as first boot sequence, I get the error:

```
Remove disks or other media.
Press any key to restart
```

So, I'm really stuck. Any suggestions?
How can I recover my system with the `grub rescue shell`?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into Live CD and run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

#### NOTE:

**sdaX-->Here X stands for the partition where you have installed  /. If its installed in `sda2` then you need to run `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`**